# How to reach XML file from REACT located in a non www folder but in another folder located at the same level of www?

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs

I'm working on a front-end app built with React and I need to access a XML file located in a non-www folder located at the same level of the www folder. The problem is that I can't relocate that file into my app because it has the settings for a camera and the app should read and write from that file. Any ideas on how can I accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to configure your webserver to provide access to the file, one way or the other. JavaScript cannot magically access something that is not exposed.

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks for your reply. I have complete access to the server but the question is how can I configure the server to accomplish that? By the way the server is Lighttpd (https://www.lighttpd.net/).